# Grid displayer: Game of Life and Langton's Ant

Tags: python, python-2.x, game-of-life, pygame, cellular-automata

#### Re-use

Given that both the Langton's Ant and the Game of Life use a **grid**, I decided to code a generic `grid_diplayer` code and use it both for GoL (Game of Life) and Langton's Ant to put into practice the principle of code re-use.

#### [Rules of Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life)

#### [Rules of Langton's Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton's_ant)

#### Pure logic

The code inside the `ant_logic` and `life_logic` cannot make contact with the outside world, any state not contained in the grid can be handled with a specific `state` variable that is returned along with the grid.

#### `grid_displayer`

`grid_displayer` shows the board after each update.

#### Commands

In the case of Game of Life I also added a bit of interactivity (in `grid_displayer`):

- <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> : Pause / Resume
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd>    : Start Again from a random board
- <kbd>+</kbd>        : Increase the x and y dimension by 10
- <kbd>-</kbd>        : Decrease the x and y dimension by 10

(Please note that <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> may create un-aesthetic effects if the size is not a sub-multiple of the screen size, just increase or decrease more to get a nicer effect)

`grid_displayer`

```
import sys, pygame
import random
from itertools import count

import life_logic
import ant_logic as ant

def show_grid(grid, screen, screen_size, color_decider):
    """
    Shows the `grid` on the `screen`.
    The colour of each cell is given by color_decider,
    a function of the form (cell -> rgb_triplet)
    """
    number_of_squares = len(grid)
    square_size = screen_size[0] // number_of_squares

    for y, row in enumerate(grid):
        for x, item in enumerate(row):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color_decider(item), (x * square_size, y * square_size, square_size, square_size), 0)

def animate_grid(grid, grid_updater, color_decider, screen_size=(600, 600), state={}):
    """
    Repeatedly calls `show_grid` to show a continually updating grid.
    """
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( screen_size )

    for ticks in count(0):
        user_inputs = pygame.event.get()
        # if user_inputs: print(repr(user_inputs))
        show_grid(grid, screen, screen_size, color_decider)
        grid, state = grid_updater(grid, user_inputs, ticks, state)

        pygame.display.flip()

def main():
    def life_next_board(current, inputs, _, state={}):
        for event in inputs:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    state["size"] -= 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    state["size"] += 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    state["paused"] = not state["paused"]
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    return life_logic.random_grid(state["size"]), state
        if not state["paused"]:
            grid = life_logic.near_map(life_logic.rules, current)
        else:
            grid = current
        return grid, state

    def life_color_decider(cell):
        return (255, 255, 255) if cell else (0, 0, 0)

    if raw_input("Do you want the [G]ame of Life or the [L]angton's Ant? ").upper().startswith("L"):
        animate_grid(
            grid = [ [True for _ in range(ant.GRID_SIZE)] for _ in range(ant.GRID_SIZE)],
            grid_updater = ant.ant_step,
            color_decider = lambda x: (255, 255, 255) if x else (0, 0, 0),
            state = {"ant" : {"x":ant.GRID_SIZE//2, "y":ant.GRID_SIZE//2, "heading":1}, "count":0 }
        )
    else:
        animate_grid(
            grid = life_logic.random_grid(life_logic.BOARD_SIZE),
            grid_updater = life_next_board,
            color_decider = life_color_decider,
            state = {"paused" : False, "size" : 30}
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`life_logic`

```
import doctest
import random

BOARD_SIZE = 30

def enumerate_2d(matrix):
    """
    Yields ((x, y), value) pairs from a given input matrix.

    >>> list( enumerate_2d( [ ["a", "b", "c"],
    ...                       ["d", "e", "f"] ] ) )
    [((0, 0), 'a'), ((1, 0), 'b'), ((2, 0), 'c'), ((0, 1), 'd'), ((1, 1), 'e'), ((2, 1), 'f')]
    """
    for y, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for x, item in enumerate(row):
            yield (x, y), item


def nears(x, y, matrix):
    """
    Yields all the neightbours of the given x, y coordinates in the matrix.
    Wraps around.

    >>> list(nears(3, 1, [ [1, 2,   3, 4 ],
    ...                    [5, 6,   7, 8 ],
    ...                    [9, 10, 11, 12] ]))
    [11, 3, 12, 4, 7]
    >>> list(nears(0, 0, [ [1, 2,   3, 4 ],
    ...                    [5, 6,   7, 8 ],
    ...                    [9, 10, 11, 12] ]))
    [6, 8, 10, 12, 5, 9, 2, 4]
    """
    for c in ( (x + 1, y + 1),
               (x - 1, y + 1),
               (x + 1, y - 1),
               (x - 1, y - 1),
               (x    , y + 1),
               (x    , y - 1),
               (x + 1, y    ),
               (x - 1, y    ) ):
        try:
            yield matrix[c[1]][c[0]]
        except IndexError:
            pass

def near_map(func, matrix):
    """
    Given a function (current, neightbours) -> new_current
    Maps the matrix by giving it as arguments the current and its neightbours.
    Wraps around.

    >>> near_map( (lambda this, nears: this + sum(nears)), [
    ...     [1,   2,  3,  4, 5 ],
    ...     [6,   7,  8,  9, 10],
    ...     [11, 12, 13, 14, 15] ])
    [[69, 63, 72, 81, 57], [69, 63, 72, 81, 57], [61, 57, 63, 69, 48]]
    """
    return list(chunks_of(len(matrix[0]), \
                [func(i, nears(x, y, matrix)) for (x, y), i in enumerate_2d(matrix)]))

def chunks_of(n, list_):
    """
    Yield successive n-sized chunks from list_.

    >>> list(chunks_of(2, "abcdef"))
    ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
    """
    for i in range(0, len(list_), n):
        yield list_[i:i + n]

def rules(me, nears):
    """
    Should the current cell `me` survive based on its neightbours (`nears`)?

    >>> rules(False, [True, True, True])
    True
    >>> rules(True, [False, False, True, False])
    False
    """
    return sum(nears) in (2, 3) if me else sum(nears) == 3

def next_board(current):
    """
    Next board of Game of Life.
    """
    return near_map(rules, current)

def random_grid(size):
    """
    Generates a random square starting grid for the Game of Life of the given `size`.
    """
    return [ [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

`ant_logic`

```
GRID_SIZE = 100

ORIENTATION_TO_DELTA = {
    0 : (0 ,-1),
    1 : ( 1, 0),
    2 : ( 0, 1),
    3 : (-1, 0)
}


def ant_step(board, _, __, state):
    x, y = state["ant"]["x"], state["ant"]["y"]
    offset = 1 if board[y][x] else -1   # White is true
    heading = (state["ant"]["heading"] + offset) % 4 # 4 cardinal directions
    delta_x, delta_y = ORIENTATION_TO_DELTA[heading]
    new_board = board[:]; new_board[y][x] = not board[y][x]
    # if state["count"] % 100 == 0: print(state["count"])
    return new_board, {"ant" : {"x": x + delta_x, "y" : y + delta_y, "heading": heading}, "count":state["count"] +1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You offered the code without a specific review question, so I take it to be a generic "please pick nits" sort of review.

Your code has exemplary style, very clear, with nicely chosen identifiers and lovely docstrings. I have no nits to pick. Bravo!

Put another way, every bit of code you write presents an argument to the Gentle Reader, and I am completely buying the argument, I believe it.